# Interleave a List with itself

Tags: java, list

Given a `List` instance, what is the most efficient way of increasing the size of the `List` by a factor of `f` such that the new elements are duplicates of the original elements, interleaved with the original array?

e.g.

```
f        = 2
Original = [a,b,c,...,x,y,z]
New      = [a,a,b,b,c,c,...,x,x,y,y,z,z]
```

My current implementation is this:

```
List< Foo > interleave( List< Foo > original, int f ) {
    int newSize = original.size() * f;
    List< Foo > interleaved = new ArrayList< Foo >( newSize );

    for( Foo foo : original ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < factor; j++ ) {
            interleaved.add( new Foo( foo ) );
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that my original list can be quite large, so performance isn't very good. I have a hunch that there is a much more efficient way to do this; does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Your solution is as efficient as it can be.

Comment: Why do you recreate the `foo` instance as well? Shouldn't the first object be the very same as in the original list? Could you use `foo.clone()` instead of the copy constructor or is there anything special in it?

Comment: @Thomas Because in reality `Foo` is an x-y pair, so x would increase with each iteration, but y stay constant.

Comment: The only way to make it more efficient is to use another approach. e.g. override `get(int)` so it calls `get(n / f)` instead.

Comment: In that cases every element is different so you have to create them all.

Comment: @Dunnie Do you need true duplicates (two separate objects with same value) or can the duplicates be just references to the original object? There is a faster solution if references can be used.

Comment: Btw, `The problem is that my original list can be quite large` - how large can they be? How do you use that for performance to be a problem? I made a simple example from what I got from your post and comments and interleaving a 1,000,000 entry list with factor 10 takes about 1.5 seconds on my system, which is approximately 10 times as long as it takes to create the initial list. So nothing out of the ordinary here. If you get worse results then the problem might be in your `Foo(foo)` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provide is well optimized, but there are some improvements that can be made; The significant ones depending on your exact needs.

---

First, if your cloned elements are going to stay with the same value as the original, or otherwise just a few of them (compared to the total) are going to have their values changed, you might want to consider a reference-based cloning instead of the current "true-clone it all" code, if not a completely different approach that doesn't even create new lists.

```
    /**
     * PROS:
     * -Very low memory-footprint, as no new objects are created in memory, just references to a single (original) object.
     * -Can be done with generalization; A single method will function for most classes and data-types, as is below.
     * 
     * CONS:
     * -If you need each clone element to be changed independently from eachother and/or the orininal, this will not work directly,
     * because any change to an reference-element will apply to all other reference-elements that point to that same Object.
     * 
     * @param <E> Sub-class generalizator. Used so that the returned list has the same sub-class as the source.
     * @param list Source list. The list containing the elements to be interleaved.
     * @param f The factor to interleave for. In effect, the number of resulting elements for each original.
     * @return A list containing the interleaved elements, with each element being a REFERENCE to the original object.
     */
    public static <E> List<E> interleaveByReference(List<E> list, int f) {
        List<E> interleaved = new ArrayList<E>(list.size() * f);
        for (E obj : list) {
            for (int i = 0; i < f; i++) {
                interleaved.add(obj);
            }
        }
        return interleaved;
    }
```

In case you are going to need just a few of your clones to change value, it might be better for your interleaved list to be reference-based, and the elements that need to be changed to be replaced individually later on.

Note however, that the effectiveness of this approach will be highly dependent on how much of your original list's elements will need to be changed; And that if too many need changes, this method, although still better in memory-footprint, will be worse in speed performance (which seems to be your main concern).

The "later on individual cloning" can be achieved with something similar to this:

```
public static void replaceWithTrueClone(List<String> list, int objIndex) {
    list.add(objIndex, new String(list.get(objIndex)));
    list.remove(objIndex + 1);
}

//OR

public static void replaceWithNewObject (List<String> list, int objIndex, String newObject) {
    list.add(objIndex, newObject);
    list.remove(objIndex + 1);
}
```

---

If most of every element is going to have independent values in the course of your program's execution, then your current method is pretty accurate already.

There are two improvements that can be made. It will be easier to show it in the code directly, so that's what I'll do:

```
    /**
     * PROS:
     * -Each element is an independent object, and can be set to independent values without much of an effort.
     * 
     * CONS:
     * -Each element has it's own allocated memory for it's values, thus having a much heavier memory footprint.
     * -Is constructor-dependent, and thus cannot be generalized as easily;
     * Each different expected class will probably need it's own method.
     * 
     * @param list Source list. The list containing the elements to be interleaved.
     * @param f The factor to interleave for. In effect, the number of resulting elements for each original.
     * @return A list containing the interleaved elements.
     * For each of the original elements, the first is a REFERENCE, and the other are CLONES.
     */
    public static List<String> interleaveByClone(List<String> list, int f) {
        List<String> interleaved = new ArrayList<String>(list.size() * f);
        for (String obj : list) {
            interleaved.add(obj); //The first element doesn't have to be cloned, I assume.
            //If it has to be cloned, delete the line above, and change 'i=1' to 'i=0' on the line below.
            for (int i = 1; i < f; i++) {
                interleaved.add(new String(obj));
            }
        }
        return interleaved;
    }

    /*
     * What was changed from the original is commented below.
     */

    public static List<String> original(List<String> original, int factor) {
        /*
         * It is unnessessary to have this 'newSize' variable. It gets needlessly maintained until the end of the method.
         * Although the impact is unworthy of measurement (negligible), it still exists.
         */
        int newSize = original.size() * factor;
        List<String> interleaved = new ArrayList<String>(newSize); //Just do the '*factor' operarion directly, instead of 'newSize'.

        for (String foo : original) {
            /*
             * If you can use the original here, that's one less cloning operation (memory-allocation, etc...) per original element.
             * A low-impact optimization, but still a good one.
             */
            for (int j = 0; j < factor; j++) {
                interleaved.add(new String(foo));
            }
        }
        return interleaved;
    }
```

---

With an original list of two million elements, and a factor of 2, I get the following average speeds over 10 runs:

- It takes 6030 (~) millis to create and fill the original list with
  2000000 different elements.
- It takes 75 (~) millis to interleave the list with the
  `interleaveByReference()` method.
- It takes 185 (~) millis to interleave the list with the
  `interleaveByClone()` method.
- It takes 210 (~) millis to interleave the list with the
  `original()` method.

Answer (score 1):

This works quite nicely without the expense of a full duplication.

```
List< String > interleave(final List< String > original, final int f ) {
    final int size = f * original.size();
    final List<String> originalCopy = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String each : original) {
        originalCopy.add(new String(each)); // <=== duplicate here.
    }
    return new AbstractList<String>() {
        @Override
        public String get(int index) {
            return originalCopy.get(index / f);
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return size;
        }            
    };
}
```

Test

```
System.out.println(interleave(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"), 2));
System.out.println(interleave(Arrays.asList("x", "y"), 3));
```

Output

```
[a, a, b, b, c, c]
[x, x, x, y, y, y]
```

Comment: What if the receiver of the list wants to add data?`size` will always be the same.If the list is not to be modified I think this is clever approach

Comment: Works fine for primitives and immutable objects, but what about mutables? You'd be returning the same object instead of "duplicates"... but then the OP didn't specify what he wanted.

Comment: @JimGarrison Solution could be modified to do a deep copy of the originalCopy variable.

Answer (score 0):

A minor speedup could be achieved by reinserting the original elements and only creating the duplicates:

```
List< Foo > interleave( List< Foo > original, int factor ) {
  int newSize = original.size() * factor ;
  List< Foo > interleaved = new ArrayList< Foo >( newSize );

  for( Foo foo : original ) {
    interleaved.add( foo );
    for( int j = 1; j < factor; j++ ) {
        interleaved.add( new Foo( foo ) );
    }
  }

  return interleaved;
}
```